# Signal the end of a series of (n) AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise

I have a web application which crawls sites in a CMS and looks for data of a certain type.

It works a lot like a recursive file/directory loop:

```
//pseudo code
var rootWeb = context.site.rootWeb();
var objectThatHoldsAllResults;
recursiveSiteSearch(rootWeb);

function recursiveSiteSearch(webSite) {
   //Get all content of a certain type and add to objectThatHoldsAllResults
   //Get all SubSites and throw them into a loop that runs recursiveSiteSearch
}
```

This application lives in the cloud, and has no idea how many subsites live in each CMS that accesses it.

Each time the loop gets all content of a certain type, it makes an AJAX call to the website.

I need to know when the recursion is done, but have no idea how to do so.

Comment: Hi Wesley, I'm a little confused.  Why can't you just put a new line of code after `recursiveSiteSearch(rootWeb)` which does whatever you need with the results.  That line would be executed after recursiveSiteSearch was done executing.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding -- if so please give me some more details about how your app works and what you'd like to do with the results.

Comment: How do you use the promises? Please show us some actual code. Each Promise lib would have a `all` function or something for bundling promises.

Comment: @Jonah Yes, that's correct, but because the final (n) AJAX calls might finish after the last recursion ends, I could miss out on data.

Comment: @Bergi the calls are made by a proprietary library published by the CMS. All we do is call `context.executeQueryAsync()` on each subsite we want to pull typed data from.

Comment: @Jonah the AJAX calls all queue up before even a single returns. If I query objectThatHoldsAllResults.length following resursiveSiteSearch, I get 0.

Comment: @Wesley, I see.  I think beetroot's idea, or some variation on it, is the way to go here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straightforwardly, recursion will have ended when execution falls through to the statement following `recursiveSiteSearch(rootWeb);`.

However, asynchronicity (ajax) within `recursiveSiteSearch` may/will(?) mean that some latent activity still exists at that point.

Therefore, you appear to need a mechanism for detecting when all promises (ie. all ajax requests initiated within the recursion) are complete.

jQuery, provides such a mechanism.

pseudo code :

```
function recursiveSiteSearch(webSite) {
    //Get all content of a certain type and add to objectThatHoldsAllResults
    //Get all SubSites and throw them into a loop that runs recursiveSiteSearch
    //Within the loop, push jqXHR objects onto the externally declared `promises` array.
}

var rootWeb = context.site.rootWeb();
var objectThatHoldsAllResults;
var promises = [];
recursiveSiteSearch(rootWeb);
jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, promises).done(function() {
    //statements here will execute when 
    //recursion has finished and all ajax 
    //requests have completed.
});
```

The reason this should work is that [jqXHR objects](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jqxhr-object) (returned by jQuery.ajax() and its shorthand forms) implement jQuery's Promise interface.

Comment: Sorry, I was away. I'll try this out immediately and let you know how it works.

Comment: Wesley, you are using SharePoint, right? If so, then you may find it tricky to merge my suggestion with the code you have already written. SharePoint may well offer a built-in Promise mechanism but the SP API is so poorly documented, I expect that few people will ever discover, let alone master, it. If you edit your question to provide more relevant detail of what goes on inside `recursiveSiteSearch()` I'll see if I can advise.

Comment: Thanks Beetroot. You are correct, this is SharePoint, and it looks like it relies on Microsoft AJAX instead of jQuery. Currently what I am using is a counter that adds +1 for every call, and subtracts -1 for every success or failure and it is working so far. I can post my code in another thread if you want to take a shot :)

Comment: Wesley, yes give it a shot and post a link to the new Q here. I can't make any promises [sic] because I find much of SharePoint's API impenetrable, but I will certainly have a look.